# current location needs page refresh in Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

i have created an application in jquery and google maps javascript v3 , in which i am displaying a user's current location after a button click.

Now the problem is some times i got pretty fine current location and sometimes at the same place its showing my current location miles away but again when i refresh the page i again got the pretty fine current location.

does anyone know how to get rid off pressing refresh button again so a user doesn't has to press the refresh on their mobile browser ??

Note:
I am testing this application in android phone which has a default browser.

Page #1 has a button and Page #2 has a map but the Page #1 and Page #2 are combined in a single 
jQuery HTML page.

Comment: Why don't you create a function that calls itself with setTimeout and inside put the code that get's your location?

Comment: i tried setTimeOut but this isn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try adding some logic using the accuracy parameter off the geolocation object (`position.coords.accuracy`). For example,

```
//if accuracy is to low
if (position.coords.accuracy =< 500) {
    //redo the geolocation
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    //update marker
    marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)})
}
 , displayError);
}
```

Comment: Do i need to write above code in side the outer getCurrentPosition ?

Comment: Mate, as it reads now, this logic should be in a function which is passed the position object, so for examble the geolocation success callback function. But this was just an example, in the future you should aim for 1 geolocation function, which is called severel times..

Comment: sometimes accuracy is too high which shows my location pretty far so is there any kind of a fixed way to set upper n lower proximity

Comment: i have tried your code and in that if the accuracy rate is low then the function will get fired again , but some time i get accuracy value too high (which is quite far from my current location) so what should i do in that case

Comment: Oh, sorry, it should be the other way around `=>`